# Negative potential energy

Tags: energy, mass, potential-energy, fusion, binding-energy

In fusion of hydrogen into helium, hydrogen has negative potential energy which adds up and results in a mass defect..

Doubts:-

Why is there negative potential energy between the nucleons in a hydrogen nucleus. Also how come potential energy is possible between the nucleons which are in stable state and constantly attract each other?
+If negative potential energy is added up then the overall negative potential energy should remain the same... Whereas , the negative potential energy results in a mass defect ...

If my understanding is wrong then kindly correct me and please explain the real exact reason why **energy is released in fusion in terms of negative potential energy and E=MC²?**